# Should I use the window's Show() or ShowDialog() method to show the main window at app startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here's an example of the first lines of code in many WPF applications using the MVVM pattern:

```
    protected override void OnStartup( StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

        MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

The code creates a MainWindow, creates a ViewModel for the MainWindow and sets the ViewModel as DataContext of the MainWindow. Then the MainWindow.Show() method is called and the UI is shown to the user.

I found out that I could also call the MainWindow.ShowDialog() method to force its visualization. Then the window must be closed by setting the DialogResult property. Apart from that everything seems to work the same way.

=> Are there any disadvantages to use ShowDialog() instead of Show() for a MainWindow?

Comment: I wouldnt use ShowDialog, since it is not built for this occasion. The main difference is that `Show` immediately returns when the window is opened. If you have to do some additional steps after opening the form, `ShowDialog` wont work, because it only returns after the Window is closed.

Comment: _"Are there any disadvantages to use ShowDialog() instead of Show() for a MainWindow?"_ -- it depends on what your goals are. I would disagree with your characterization of "many WPF applications", as most will use the default template provided by Visual Studio, which doesn't involve overriding the `OnStartup()` method at all, never mind all the explicit window creation, data context setting, and window showing you claim is typical. Blocking a method like `OnStartup()` is generally considered bad form, but maybe you have what you think is a good reason. Seems primarily a matter of opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PeterDuniho. My characterization referred to "many WPF applications using the MVVM pattern". You won't use the default template provided by Visual Studio for that! Besides that I think you're right that blocking `OnStartup()` seems to be wrong. Originally I thought: What the heck should be done after calling the Show(Modal) method? The UI is ready and the logic can start to run in the (MainWindow)ViewModel world. But I forgot that at least `base.OnStartup(e)` should be called in the overridden method.

Comment: _"You won't use the default template provided by Visual Studio for that!"_ -- huh? _All_ of the WPF programs I write use MVVM, and _all_ of them use the default template provided by Visual Studio. MVVM does not in even the remotest way exclude the use of the default VS template for WPF programs (it would be remarkably silly if it did, frankly, since WPF is _designed_ to be used with the MVVM pattern).

Comment: My first question here on StackOverflow and I learn a lot about the difficulties of written conversation! ;-) Of course everyone starts with the default template for WPF applications but you have to adjust it to use MVVM. Anywhere in your app you have to set the DataContext for your MainWindow to benefit from DataBinding. And as your DataContext/ViewModel probably has further dependencies you have to create it in any way and somehow inject these dependencies. You won't do that in the MainWindow.xaml.cs. So tell me how do your WPF applications stick MainWindowView/-ViewModel together?